# What's the best way to amalgamate the 2 queries below

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the query below as part of a larger query to create a table.  As I'm new to SQL, this was done in a very step-by-step manner so that I could easily understand the individual steps in the query and what each part was doing.

However, I've now been tasked to make the below 2 parts of the query more efficient by joining them together, and this is where I'm struggling.

I feel like I should be creating a single table rather than 2 and that the single table should contain all of the columns/values that I require.  However, I am not at all sure of the syntax required to make this happen or the order in which I need to re-write the query.

Is anyone able to offer any advice?

Many thanks

```
sys_type as (select nvl(dw_start_date,sysdate) date_updated, id, descr
from scd2.scd2_table_a
inner join year_month_period
on 1=1
WHERE batch_end_date BETWEEN dw_start_date and NVL(dw_end_date,sysdate)),

sys_type_2 as (select -1 as sys_typ_id,
'Unassigned' as sys_typ_desc, 
sysdate as date_updated
from dual
union
select id as sys_typ_id, descr as sys_typ_desc, date_updated
from sys_type),
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL there.)

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean: Which database product are you using?

Comment: If I said Oracle SQL, would that answer the question?

Comment: Run 'SELECT * FROM v$version;' and post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle database, the queries above seem fine. I don't think you can make them more efficient just by 'joining' them (joining defined very loosely here. Is there a performance issue?

I think you can get better results by tuning your first inline query 'sys_type'.

You have a cartesian product there. Do you need that? Why don't you put the condition in the where clause as the join clause? 
Basically

```
sys_type as (select nvl(dw_start_date,sysdate) date_updated, id, descr
from scd2.scd2_table_a
inner join year_month_period
on (batch_end_date BETWEEN dw_start_date and NVL(dw_end_date,sysdate)))
```